# Symfony2 log in as another user, when already logged in

Tags: authentication, symfony

I am using the following code to log in as a user, when I am not logged in at all;

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->getRequest(), $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

try
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request')->getSession()->set('_security_' . "main", serialize($token));
}
catch(InactiveScopeException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}       

return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show'));
```

I use the same code again once logged in to re-login as another user. Only this same code fails when I am already logged in.

So if I am anon it works, but once I am authenticated it fails.

Do I need to do something extra so that this works even when I am already logged in and want to log in as another user?

Comment: Best way to find out is debugging the entire request (especially the kernel.request and kernel.response events).

Just an idea: try redirect instead of forward!

Comment: Edited. I meant to show a redirect and not a forward, the forward works sorry. The redirect does not.